# What should SDK/target bet set to not get "Application Not Installed"

Tags: android, xamarin.android

For an internal Android app that we are upgrading, I get "application not installed" when the new version (i.e. **2.1.1**) tries to overwrite the older (**1.0.54**). Both use the same keystore.

What's interesting, **1.0.54** can successfully install over the **2.1.1** version, but not the other way around. I have to uninstall **1.0.54** then install **2.1.1**.

- Version **1.0.54** was packaged with: Minimum `SDK=15`, Target `SDK=15`
- Version **2.1.1** was packaged with: Minimum `SDK=18`, Target `SDK=23`, compile =23 (Android 6)

In version **2.1.1** I tried setting the Minimum `SDK=15` to match the **1.0.54** release, but that didn't work.

Is this perhaps due to Android 4.0 (Ice cream Sandwich) not being forward compatible to Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)?

Comment: "2.1.1 can successfully install over the 1.0.54 version", you mean the other way round like "1.0.54 can successfully install over the 2.1.1 version", right?

Comment: Yes, apologies - I messed that description up.    2.1.1 cannot install over 1.0.54 without first uninstalling 1.0.54.  However, 1.0.54 can install over 2.1.1.  I point this out in case someone says the issue is with keys.

Comment: Have you checked the version codes of both apks? For additional error details you should watch logcat while trying to install the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to check the **Version Code** of your app packages to ensure that the newer app has a higher number.

[Android has two fields for version information, one is Version Name, and the other is Version Code/Number](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html). The "2.1.1" and "1.0.54" referenced in the question are **Version Names**.

For the purposes of app versioning, Android completely ignores the Version Name field. Its exists just to convey version information to users of your app.
App versioning (upgrades/downgrades) is based entirely on the Version Code field.